# Use TensorFlow to find the position numarically minimizing a quantized value map without knowing the underlying function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, optimization, scipy

I have a quantized 2D map of function values, whose function I do not know. I want to find the continuous position of the minimum of this map.

I can do this easily using `scipy`, but I would like to use TensorFlow for this because in reality, I have a very complicated compute graph I would like to derive automatically which works like a charm using TF. This requires basically a mixture of numerical and analytical gradient computation.

In the following, you'll find a very small example in the form of the Rosenbrock function capturing the part I'm not able to express in TF but in `scipy`.

**Using scipy**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
from scipy.optimize import minimize

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2., 2., 1000),
                     np.linspace(-3., 1., 1000))

x0 = np.array([-1.5, -.5])
origin = np.array([-2, -3])
spacing = np.array([4. / 1000, 4. / 1000])

# the quantized function I want to minimize, can be anything
rosenbrock = ((1 - xx)**2 + 100*(yy - xx**2)**2).T

# it is NOT that simple ;)
print('Quantized min at: ',
      spacing * np.unravel_index(np.argmin(rosenbrock), rosenbrock.shape)
      + origin)

def rosen(x):
    idx = ((x - origin) / spacing).reshape(1, 2)
    return map_coordinates(rosenbrock, idx.T)

rosenbrock_grad0, rosenbrock_grad1 = np.gradient(rosenbrock)
def rosen_der(x):
    idx = ((x - origin) / spacing).reshape(1, 2)
    return np.array([map_coordinates(rosenbrock_grad0, idx.T)[0],
                     map_coordinates(rosenbrock_grad1, idx.T)[0]])

res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='BFGS', jac=rosen_der, options={'disp': True})
print('Print continuous BFGS result:', res)
```

**But how to use tensorflow?**

```py
x_tf = tf.Variable(x0)
idx_tf = (x_tf - origin) / spacing

# how to express this as an OP where I can supply gradients
# in form a numerical derivatives?
f_tf = ???

opt_tf = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(f_tf)

with tf.Session() as session:
    for i in range(100):
        session.run(opt_tf)
        print('%i: f=%f x=%s' % (i + 1, session.run(f_tf), session.run(x_tf)))
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but maybe you're looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients ?